# Path for fonts?

Tags: fonts, home-directory

I searched already for this question and got a page on here where someone answered with *"go to home/username/.fonts"* or somesuch. I ran into a couple problems:

1. No such folder existed.
2. I discovered there was a "home" above "Home" in the hierarchy. Went there, double-clicked on my username, it took me back to Home. **Which still did not contain any folder with the word "font" or "fonts" in it.** There is an "etc" immediately followed by "Music." Nothing before "Calibre Library" and nothing after "Zombie Shooter 2 Saves" either.

So yeah, there is no *home/username/.fonts* or *home/username/fonts* or anything of the sort. So where in the 24 Hecks does the OS ***actually*** keep the Fonts folder? And if anyone tells me home/username/fonts or whatever, I may have to scream.

I have Ubuntu 12, I think, if that helps.

Answer (score 10):

The directory `/home` itself is not any user's home directory. Rather, this directory contains the home directories of all the users of the system (except root), the name of each user's home direcotry being the name of the user. So, if your user name is `user266566`, then there will be a directory `/home/user266566`. That is *your* home directory. When *you* are in that directory, the file manager/shell recognizes that and indicates it in some way, such as capitalizing the H in Home, showing a house icon, or replacing the `/home/user266566` with `~` (in the case of a shell).

If it helps, `/home` is akin to `C:\Users` in Windows.

As for the font directories, you can install fonts either available for all users or simply for yourself. If you want a font available to just yourself, put it in `~/.fonts`, where `~` refers to your home directory. If the directory `.fonts` doesn't exist in your home folder, make one. Also keep in mind that any file (including directories) that begins with a dot (`.`) will appear hidden unless you set your file manager to show hidden files. 
So, if you can't find `.fonts`, perhaps the file manager is set to not show hidden files. (The key sequence Ctrl + H is a convention to toggle between showing and hiding "dot" files.)

If you want to install fonts system-wide (i.e. for all users), you'll need administrative privileges. The easiest way is to install fonts though the package manager if they're available as packages. These fonts will get installed in `/usr/share/fonts` (and within that directory, most likely in `truetype`). However, if you want to manually install fonts, a better place to put them is `/usr/local/share/fonts` since that nicely separates the fonts installed by the package manager and the fonts you installed manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can search for the directory by opening a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
and entering:

```
find ~ -name fonts
```

(for me it's .local/share/fonts)

Answer (score 3):

the .font folder is a hidden folder ,you may have to create it first.
you can install new fonts by putting them in it.
Now for the location of intalled fonts you can find their locations in your fonts.conf file 
`gedit /etc/fonts/fonts.conf` 
mine are in `/usr/share/fonts`

Comment: This showed me where is my font directory on lubuntu.